# Modeling non-exclusive choices

Tags: modeling, panel-data, model-selection, conditional-probability, logit

I am trying to model votes by individuals on a number of bills over time using bill-specific characteristics as explanatory variables. Imagine that the same bill is offered to them albeit with minor changes from year to year. **I want to determine what sort of changes in text of the bill will make individuals vote yes, if they had voted no before. (i.e. what is it about the bill features that makes individual switch from no(0) to yes (1) for a certain bill).**

My dependent variable is 0-1 whether a person voted yes at a given time. My main explanatory variables are characteristics of each bills (bills are scored on a number of dimensions). Ideally, I would want to model both bill-specific and individual-specific independent variables (perhaps via interaction?).

**I am really confused about what model i should use. A simple individual-fixed effects logit is not a perfect model. I was also thinking of conditional logit, but the choices are non-exclusive and at any given time an individual is choosing whether to vote yes on only one bill. I would really appreciate any model suggestions.**

My dataframe looks like this (but can be reworked):

```
I year   bill1 bill2 bill3 bill4 billfeature1 billfeature2  billfeature3
1   1990  0     1    1       0         5                3              1  
1   1991  0     0    1       1         6                3              3  
1   1992  0     0    0       0         7                4              6  
1   1993  0     0    1       1         7                5              7  
1   1994  1     1    1       1         8                6              8  
2   1990  0     1    1       1         5                3              1      
2   1991  0     0    1       0         6                3              3        
2   1992  0     0    0       0         7                4              6  
2   1993  0     0    1       1         7                5              7
2   1994  0     0    1       1         8                6              8
```